# Configure enterprise Splunk in docker, so services can log to HTTP Event Collector over HTTP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, splunk

I'm trying to set up and configure enterprise Splunk in docker for local testing. I want to be able to send logs to the HTTP event collector (HEC) via the docker logging provider for splunk - see [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/splunk/).

I can configure a HEC token by specifying `SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN` as an environment variable when I run the splunk container (see docker-compose below), but I want to be able to call the HEC endpoint over HTTP (i.e. without SSL). If SSL is enabled in `/opt/splunk/etc/apps/splunk_httpinput/local/inputs.conf`, my test service (see docker-compose below) doesn't work - I get the following error:

> Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver:
> Options https://localhost:8088/services/collector/event/1.0: x509:
> cannot validate certificate for localhost because it doesn't
> contain any IP SANs.

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
   skynet:

services:

   splunk:
      image: splunk/splunk:latest
      environment:
         SPLUNK_START_ARGS: "--accept-license"
         SPLUNK_PASSWORD: $SPLUNK_PASSWORD
         SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN: $SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN
      ports:
         - 8000:8000
         - 8088:8088
      networks:
         - skynet

   test:
      image: ryans/test-service
      depends_on:
         - splunk
      environment:
         WAIT_FOR_IT: http://localhost:8000
      ports:
         - 5001:5001
      logging:
         driver: splunk
         options:
            splunk-url: https://localhost:8088
            splunk-token: $SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN
            splunk-insecureskipverify: 'true'
      networks:
         - skynet
```

Interestingly, if I comment out my test service and just run docker-compose with only the Splunk container; I can call the Splunk HEC URL over HTTPS using cURL e.g.

```
curl -k https://localhost:8088/services/collector -H 'Authorization: Splunk abcd1234' -d '{\"event\": \"Hello from event collector\"}'
```

In the Splunk web interface; if I go to `settings > Data Inputs > HTTP Event Collector > Global Settings` and explicitly disable Enable SSL; I can then send logs to the HEC endpoint over HTTP (using cURL), and I can bring up my test service without error (and logs start coming through to Splunk).

```
docker run -p 5001:5001 --log-driver=splunk --log-opt splunk-token=abcd1234 --log-opt splunk-url=http://localhost:8088 ryans/test-service
```

My question is how can I get the `Enable SSL` setting to default to disabled/off?

FYI., I tried overriding the `splunk/splunk` docker image to manually set enableSSL in `/opt/splunk/etc/apps/splunk_httpinput/local/inputs.conf`, but for some reason (when I exec into the running container) it's reverted back to enabled/on i.e. `enableSSL = 1`...

Dockerfile:

```
FROM splunk/splunk:latest
COPY ./inputs.conf /opt/splunk/etc/apps/splunk_httpinput/local/inputs.conf
```

inputs.conf:

```
[http]
disabled = 0
enableSSL = 0

[http://splunk_hec_token]
disabled = 0
token = abcd1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a `default.yml` as detailed here?

https://splunk.github.io/docker-splunk/ADVANCED.html#usage

### Example

```yaml
splunk:
  hec:
    enable: True
    ssl: false
    port: 8088
    # hec.token is used only for ingestion (receiving Splunk events)
    token: <default_hec_token>
```

Comment: thanks @im_baby - it worked! just added the following environment var to my docker-compose script: `SPLUNK_DEFAULTS_URL: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yesmarket/54f292af4a3f0bd64d135528758bd0f8/raw/b583ecd81367d124042be4e7d2b9928147066e80/default.yml`

Comment: I was looking for the same answer and found that setting the environment variable SPLUNK_HEC_SSL=false achieved the same result.